# Spock/Geb test pollution

Tags: testing, grails, cookies, spock, geb

I'm getting some sort of test pollution. When I run failing tests individually, they pass.  When I run them all together, I get errors. The errors are not related to database. I can't understand the errors. For instance:
page:

```
errorModule (wait: true) { module ErrorModule }
```

errorModule:
    static content = {
        error (required: false) { $("h3.error") }
    }

spec:

```
assert page.errorModule
```

Gives exception:
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"tag name","selector":"html"}

I don't understand because the content of the module is not required. Also, what pollution from another test could cause this? My tests are too numerous to list.

My only idea is the cookies that are getting set not by my program. There are a bunch of cookies with odd names such as "ba743b", "kvcd", "kn_ai", etc with cryptic values such as "1361461306476" and "1.1361461306.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)". Does anyone know where these cookies might come from and how to clear them at the end of a test? Is that even important? They are not session cookies, they have expiration dates. I don't know how to delete these cookies which I do not think my code creates. But it could have nothing to do with this.

Comment: Your `page.errorModule` is required, you've set `errorModule.error` to be not required. OTOH it would be nice if you have a name Engineer.

Comment: But with the content not required, I thought it might not matter. What confuses me is that this only happens once in a blue moon, not for all page calls. The content of the errorModule is almost never there. Thanks for your comment. I will try errorModule(wait: true, required: false) and assert page.errorModule?.etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use Firefox to execute your tests? Does the error happen just after switching pages?

If so then you are probably hitting a bug in Firefox driver when it returns control to test code while still (re)loading the page. The error also sometimes shows up in `at()` checks when title is an empty string. What I tend to do is add a call to `at()`/`verifyAt()` just before the line where the exception is being thrown. It's a dirty hack but I cannot think about anything better and it seems to always work.